# All black image after running r.to.vect

Tags: qgis

What am I doing wrong if my raster image becomes completely black after polygonising the tif file.
I tried converting the following raster image into vector

[image: source raster]

And got this as output

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is that dust or data?

Comment: i can't understand either why polygonizing that creates vectors can have any effect on raster

Comment: That's not dust, it's data.

Comment: I mean... what do you expect is the outcome ? And how the hell should the algorithm know what you want to do ? Do you really think it can create a map from an aerial photograph? Could be possible in the future with deep learning, but I guess we're far from that. Btw: what is wrong about taking screenshots instead of photographing your screen ...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you can't just boldly convert any random image to vector, it will not work the way you seem to expect. You should have a look at **image classification techniques** to understand exactly what you are doing priori to vectorizing anything.

Comment: It's not a random image, It's a tif file of a map I've been working on.

Comment: It looks to me like a aerial photograph. You will need to be much more precise in your question (for example by adding the image metadata)  to help us know what you are doing precisely. If you did work on this raster, then it should be in integer to be "convertible" correctly, but from my point of view and experience, converting THIS image (as it is displayed) to vector will not achieve much, you will just have a vector mess of hundred of individual polygons.